# Handling and disposing of discarded tasks c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, service, task, task-parallel-library

I have a windows service that has methods within it that fire and forgets tasks.  I would like some clarity on how these are handled when the windows service is stopped or restarted?

For clarity, I'm using this code:
_ = Task.Run(() => DoSomething());

If this task is mid-way through execution, how does the windows service treat the stopping, as well as the restarting of a service?

(1)
My assumption on restart is that the OnStop() method of the service will get called, the fire and forget task will continue.  The OnStart() will then get called, and again the fire and forget task should continue.  The task will get disposed on completion.  Is there any other management of tasks or memory that happens automatically by the .net runtime in this process?

(2)
My assumption on stop is that the OnStop() method of the service will get called, the fire and forget task will continue.  The OnStop method will return, then the service will get killed, therefore killing the fire and forget task.

(3)
Therefore, using fire and forget tasks, by my own assumptions, should not prevent a service from either stopping or restarting.

Note: I'm having trouble stopping and restarting a service.  So I'm trying to determine the behavior here.  Can anybody please confirm or deny my assumptions?  Thanks.

Comment: Your assumptions match my assumptions, without having any deep knowledge about windows services myself. What kind of problems do you have when stopping and restarting the service? Also how many fire-and-forget tasks are in flight at any given moment on average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire-and-forget tasks are always risky.  If an unhandled exception occurs within a fire-and-forget task, it will <del>tear down your whole process</del> leave your process in a potentially undefined and potentially unstable state, because there might be corrupted data or allocated resources.

In services, fire-and-forget tasks pose another risk.  See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/multithreaded-services):

> If the service reports to the SCM that the service has stopped before
>   all threads have exited, it is possible that the SCM will interpret
>   this as a contradiction. This might result in a state where the
>   service cannot be stopped or restarted.

My advise is to avoid fire-and-forget tasks.  When you fire such a task, add it in a list.  In your `OnStop` method, go through this list and await all tasks to completion.  If you have tasks you can cancel, cancel them and again wait for them to complete.

Comment: *"If an unhandled exception occurs within a fire-and-forget task, it will tear down your whole process."* <--- [Not true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception#remarks) for .NET Framework 4.5 and later.

Comment: True.  But this doesn't make the problem less serious.  Your process will be in undefined state.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I have cancelled my tasks on dispose of my objects, and ensure dispose is called on OnStop.  That quote from documentation is interesting.  That could be what's happening for me.